# UIView bringSubviewToFront: does *not* bring view to front

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

I am implementing a simple iOS solitaire game that allows the user to drag the cards around in the usual way. The cards are represented with the `UIView` subclass `CardView`. All the card view's are siblings which are subviews of `SolitaireView`. The following snippet tries to "bring a card to the front" so that it is above all the other views as it is being dragged:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   if (touch.view.tag == CARD_TAG) {
      CardView *cardView = (CardView*) touch.view;
      ...
      [self bringSubviewToFront:cardView];
      ...
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, the card's z-order remains unchanged during the drag. In the images below, I am dragging the King. Notice how it is correctly on top the Nine in the left image, but is incorrectly under the Two (under the entire stack actually) in the right image:

[image]  [image]

I also tried alter the `layer.zPosition` property as well to no avail.
How can I bring the card view to the front during the drag? I am mystified.

Comment: I discovered that `bringSubviewToFront:` triggers the view's 'needsLayout' flag to be set. My `layoutSubviews` method was also calling `bringSubviewToFront:` thus reverting all the view z-orders back to their initial state!

Comment: Then whats the solution for this? I am also having same kind of requirements, where from list of cards, if i select any of the middle order card, it should come up, then come to the front. but my animation is not working because of bringSubviewToFront: method

Comment: If you stick with using UIView subclasses then you need to mark the card being dragged so that layoutSubviews can place it on top. I actually switched to using CALayers as mentioned below.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please place the code for that.

Comment: A code snippet is listed below.

Comment: @Mrunal Source code now at https://github.com/wcochran/solitaire-iOS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confirmed. `bringSubviewToFront:` causes `layoutSubview` to be invoked. Since my version of `layoutSubviews` sets the z-orders on all the views, this was undoing the z-order I was setting in the `touchesBegan:withEvent` code above. Apple should mention this side effect in the `bringSubviewToFront` documentation.

Instead of using a `UIView` subclass, I created a `CALayer` subclass named `CardLayer`. I handle the touch in my `KlondikeView` subclass as listed below. topZPosition is an instance var that tracks the highest zPosition of all cards. Note that modifying the `zPosition` is usually animated -- I turn this off in the code below:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
   CGPoint hitTestPoint = [self.layer convertPoint:touchPoint
                                           toLayer:self.layer.superlayer];
   CALayer *layer = [self.layer hitTest:hitTestPoint];

   if (layer == nil) return;

   if ([layer.name isEqual:@"card"]) {
     CardLayer *cardLayer = (CardLayer*) layer;
     Card *card = cardLayer.card;

     if ([self.solitaire isCardFaceUp:card]) {
        //...                                                                                                            
        [CATransaction begin]; // disable animation of z change                                                                  
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue
                         forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];              
        cardLayer.zPosition = topZPosition++; // bring to highest z

        // ... if card fan, bring whole fan to top

        [CATransaction commit];
        //...                                                                                                            
     }
     // ...                                                                                                             
   }

}
```

Comment: I think using `UIView`'s for playing cards may have been a bad design choice -- I don't think they really were intended for this. I think I'll step back and use `CALayer`'s instead.